# A question about chess literature

Tags: books, recommendations

I am looking for a chess book written in a very engaging style and thoroughly professional manner. The book should be more along philosophical and psychological lines rather than notations and arithmetic.

I would appreciate any help, preferably from those who are keen chess literature lovers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check out books by GM Jonathan Rowson. As well as being a GM he is a philosopher. After his first degree in Philosophy, Politics and Economics at Oxford University he spent a year at Harvard University before doing a PhD in Wisdom at Bristol University. He is currently director of the Social Brain Centre at the RSA (UK Royal Society for the encouragement of Arts). Most of his chess books have a strong philosophical and psychological content and bias.

You should check out:

- The Seven Deadly Chess Sins
- Chess for Zebras
- The Moves That Matter: A Chess Grandmaster on the Game of Life

Answer (score 2):

You will probably find interesting the chess books of David Bronstein, specially The sorcerer´s apprentice. He was an interesting person, and has dissertations about different topics in his books. Even though most of them are chess analysis, he enjoys explaining about psychology, artificial intelligence game style and such.

Comment: Thank you, @SharkCaller! Will get books by Bronstein! :)

Answer (score 2):

One book which I liked, when I was a child, is *Chess for Tigers* by *Simon Webb*.

However, this book is pretty old (the first edition was published in 1978), and at least the tip to write moves down before moving isn't allowed today anymore.